# how do i parse json with same multiple key:value pairs in python which later i need to sum

Tags: python, json

I need to parse the JSON file which looks like the same as in the example below. I need to add each properties values with other properties values to club everyone together like `p_30_34_yrs` with other properties `p_30_34_yrs` and so on. I need JSON file as an outcome with these added values- `p_30_34_yrs` together, p_tot together and so on. Please help me out as I am very new to Python. I am able to parse it through `load()` and giving me `dict` as well but when I go like `dict["features"]` it converts it into `list` and even in `list` I am unable to get each properties keys-values, on which I apply `sum()`.

```
Example:
{
"type":"..",
"box":[..],
"crs":{
..
},
"features":[
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [..]
},
      "properties": {
        "p_30_34_yrs": 421,
        "p_tot": 3210,
        "year": "2014",
        "p_75_79_yrs": 30,
        "p_40_44_yrs": 259,
        "p_55_59_yrs": 174,
        "p_65_69_yrs": 96
      },
      "id": "lga_nrp_people_2010_2014.fid--2ea3ac96_1631a637772_-4cb1"
    },
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          ..
     ]
      },
      "properties": {
         "p_30_34_yrs": 2316,
         "p_tot": 22690,
         "year": "2014",
         "p_75_79_yrs": 461,
         "p_40_44_yrs": 1211,
         "p_55_59_yrs": 1031,
         "p_65_69_yrs": 1071
       },
       "id": "lga_nrp_people_2010_2014.fid--2ea3ac96_1631a637772_-4cb0"
    },
and same way 6 more times.
]
}
```

Comment: `features` is indeed a JSON array, which becomes a Python list. It's unclear what you tried to do with that, or what the problem was.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html Read a book on python, complete some online tutorial, it will help you. You know too little about programming for anything else to help you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (test code)?

```
jsn = {
    "type": "..",
    "box": "[..]",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": "[..]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "p_30_34_yrs": 421,
                "p_tot": 3210,
                "year": "2014",
                "p_75_79_yrs": 30,
                "p_40_44_yrs": 259,
                "p_55_59_yrs": 174,
                "p_65_69_yrs": 96
            },
            "id": "lga_nrp_people_2010_2014.fid--2ea3ac96_1631a637772_-4cb1"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "p_30_34_yrs": 2316,
                "p_tot": 22690,
                "year": "2014",
                "p_75_79_yrs": 461,
                "p_40_44_yrs": 1211,
                "p_55_59_yrs": 1031,
                "p_65_69_yrs": 1071
            },
            "id": "lga_nrp_people_2010_2014.fid--2ea3ac96_1631a637772_-4cb0"
        }
    ]
}


data = jsn["features"]

props = {"p_30_34_yrs": 0,
                "p_tot": 0,
                "p_75_79_yrs": 0,
                "p_40_44_yrs": 0,
                "p_55_59_yrs": 0,
                "p_65_69_yrs": 0}

for feat in data:
    if "properties" in feat:
        if "p_30_34_yrs" in feat["properties"]: props["p_30_34_yrs"] += feat["properties"]["p_30_34_yrs"]
        if "p_tot" in feat["properties"]: props["p_tot"] += feat["properties"]["p_tot"]
        if "p_75_79_yrs" in feat["properties"]: props["p_75_79_yrs"] += feat["properties"]["p_75_79_yrs"]
        if "p_40_44_yrs" in feat["properties"]: props["p_40_44_yrs"] += feat["properties"]["p_40_44_yrs"]
        if "p_55_59_yrs" in feat["properties"]: props["p_55_59_yrs"] += feat["properties"]["p_55_59_yrs"]
        if "p_65_69_yrs" in feat["properties"]: props["p_65_69_yrs"] += feat["properties"]["p_65_69_yrs"]

print(props)
```

Comment: Thankyou everyone for motivating me and thankyou to Mika72 esp, this code worked. Thankyou so much.

Comment: No props, glad to help you. Up-votes for helping solution(s) highly appreciated.